# How can I wipe all databases and users from a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

Okay, here is the story.

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate box with a SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard installation that I inherited from a person who left the company long before I started at my company. No documentation about the users has been left.

I don't need any of users other than having the ability to set a `sa` password and don't need any of the databases currently on the box.

The only reason I can't remove SQL Server from the box is because I don't have the original media in this office and would have trouble getting the media from the other office. I need the standard install because one of the databases I want to load is 70GB in size (they stored images in tables).

Is there a way to just start fresh?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you can get access to the box (if you need to recover access, [see the link Kin already pointed out](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/)), you need to:

- **Drop all user databases**. Please run the `PRINT` first and make sure you're not dropping anything you may regret. You may want to take backups of all databases first just in case.

  ```
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @sql += N'
    DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name)
    + N';' 
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE name NOT IN (N'master',N'tempdb',N'model',N'msdb');

  PRINT @sql;
  -- EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
  ```
- **Drop all non-system logins.** Again, please run the `PRINT` command first, and look the list over *very carefully*. I have a filter there to prevent dropping yourself if you are logged in via Windows Authentication, but you may want to add additional specific filters in the event you are logged in as `sa` or similar and don't want to drop your Windows login.

  ```
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @sql+= N'
    DROP LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
  FROM sys.server_principals 
  WHERE name <> N'sa'
  AND name NOT LIKE N'##%'
  AND name NOT LIKE N'NT [AS]%'
  AND [type] IN ('R', 'S', 'U', 'G')
  AND principal_id > 256
  AND name <> SUSER_SNAME(); -- don't drop yourself!

  PRINT @sql;
  -- EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
  ```
- **Correct the default database for any logins you keep**. You may find you can lock yourself out if your default database no longer exists. So, set your login to default to `master` or `tempdb`:

  ```
  ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\Login] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = tempdb;
  ```
- **Correct any jobs/maintenance plans that reference old databases.** You'll need to look through the list manually and identify anything that touches these databases, otherwise they'll start failing. You can get a starting list with this, but this won't necessarily be a complete list - it won't tell you if the job uses ad hoc SQL that references a database with three-part naming or calls a stored procedure that does so. Thankfully you won't have to worry about synonyms (unless some evil person put synonyms in system databases).

  ```
  SELECT j.name 
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js
      WHERE js.job_id = j.job_id
      AND js.database_name NOT IN (N'msdb',N'master',N'tempdb',N'model')
  );
  ```

  In fact, you may want to run this step first, so that you can clean up all the jobs before they start failing. I'd also validate that all the jobs that remain still have valid owners. You'll have to correct any of these jobs after you delete any logins:

  ```
  SELECT j.name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM sys.server_principals AS p
      WHERE p.sid = j.owner_sid
  );
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get logged into the box.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need any of users other than having the ability to set an sa password and don't need any of the databases currently on the box.

There are ways that you can use to [reset sa password](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2011/06/14/tips-amp-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what.aspx) or [refer to Aaron's article on MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/). For dropping all the databases, you can just use

```
select 'DROP DATABASE '+ name + char(10) + 'go'
from sys.databases where database_id > 4
```

> The only reason I can't remove sql from the box is because I don't have the original media in this office and would have trouble getting the media from the other office. I need the standard install because one of the databases I want to load is 70GB in size (they stored images in tables).

Why not install another instance of SQL Server e.g. a named instance called `INSTANCE2` or something similar that suits your needs.

BTW, there is no Windows 2007 version.

Comment: `Why not install another instance of SQL Server` -> `I don't have the original media`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed, but its still somewhat unclear as OP is telling `I need the standard install because one of the databases I want to load`. I assume starting fresh means clean up everything on the server - logins, all databases, etc. OP has not mentioned what edition and version he is using ?

Comment: I was only explaining why the OP can't just install another instance - they don't have the disc and presumably can't get it easily or download it from MSDN/Volume Licensing. So instead they want to strip the existing instance down.

Comment: I do not have the original media or access to the MSDN copy.

Comment: I do not have the original media or access to the MSDN copy.

@AaronBertrand I tried using the instructions from your well written article about using PsExec.  I am able to login to SSMS but though I am logged in as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM the Object Explorer does not display any databases OR have any security options in either the explorer on the menu options.

Comment: @MichaelBrennan-White Then I would suggest waiting until you can get the original media or access to the MSDN copy. I have no idea what is causing the current issue - if the instance is up then you should have access to security options. I don't think anyone here can fix this for you without having direct access to your machine (and maybe not even then). Just install a clean instance when you can and stop fighting with whatever this person left behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Cursor for Dropping All DBs

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR (64)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR (255)

DECLARE DROPDB CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB')

OPEN DROPDB
FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'DROP DATABASE ' + @DBName
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC @SQL
    FETCH next FROM DROPDB INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE DROPDB
DEALLOCATE DROPDB
```